# PostgreSQL installation done but commands are no working

Tags: postgresql, centos6.5

I have installed PostgreSQL on my CentOS 6.5

I have installed the same with
http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload

Now Postgres is running on 5432 that I have checked with

```
netstat -ant|grep 5432
```

but when I run a command like `postgres` or `psql`
I am getting error that

```
command not found
```

Please find attached image of the same.

[image]

Comment: You need to put those programs into your `PATH`

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+change+PATH&t=hd&ia=web

Comment: done. but now when I hit command psql, it asks for password and when I put the password which I have set at the time of installation. it says invalid password.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to be doing this as the root user and not as the postgres user?

If you login as the postgres user you'll have the right path and "psql" will connect as the postgres user.

Alternatively, you could say "psql -U postgres" and then when you're prompted for a password, the one that you selected at install time should work.